# Find the value of $h$ so that the vector $(2,4,3)$ is the image through $T$ of the vector $(-2/3,4/3,-1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation that reflects any vector about the $xz$-plane then multiplies its length by $h>0$. Find the value of $h$ so that the vector $(2,4,3)$ is the image through $T$ of the vector $\left(-\cfrac{2}{3},\cfrac{4}{3},-1\right)$

Can anyone help me in understanding this question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is no such $h>0$ since you know that $T$ does the following:
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{array}
\right)\mapsto h\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
-y\\
z\\
\end{array}
\right) $$ So we'd need a $h$ to satisfy:
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
4\\
3\\
\end{array}
\right)\mapsto h\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
-4\\
3\\
\end{array}
\right) $$ but we are told that the vector $(2,3,4)$ is mapped to $(-2/3,4/3,-1)$ by $T$, so:
$$ h\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
-4\\
3\\
\end{array}\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{2}{3}\\
\frac{4}{3}\\
-1\\
\end{array}\right) $$
but then what positive $h$ would satisfy $2h=-2/3$ etc.